# HELP unable to launch roscore

Tags: ros, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I am having trouble launching roscore. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 in a virtualbox VM. This is after rebooting the machine so I have no other ROS processes running. I am able to ping sn-VirtualBox2 just fine
I have previously had no problems running ros. ANy insights would be appreciated

```
sn:/opt/ros/indigo$ roscore
... logging to /home/sn/.ros/log/4f95944c-d6b2-11e6-8e27-0800271175be/roslaunch-sn-VirtualBox2-2858.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://sn-VirtualBox2:39912/
ros_comm version 1.11.20


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.20

NODES

roscore cannot run as another roscore/master is already running. 
Please kill other roscore/master processes before relaunching.
The ROS_MASTER_URI is http://sn-VirtualBox2:11311/
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
sn:/opt/ros/indigo$
```

Here is the log file:

```
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,186: Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,190: Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,190: roslaunch starting with args ['roscore', '--core']
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,190: roslaunch env is {'MANDATORY_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/
/ubuntu.mandatory.path', 'ROS_DISTRO': 'indigo', 'ROS_LOG_FILENAME': '/home/sn/.ros/log/3a8f14ce-d6ad-11e6-872a-0800271175be/roslaunch-sn-VirtualBox2-2777.log', 'XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR': '/var/lib/lightdm-data/sn', 'GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID': 'this-is-deprecated', 'GTK_IM_MODULE': 'ibus', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH': '/opt/ros/indigo/lib/pkgconfig', 'ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES': '', 'CPATH': '/opt/ros/indigo/include', 'LOGNAME': 'sn', 'WINDOWID': '29360139', 'PATH': '/opt/ros/indigo/bin:/opt/ghc/7.8.4/bin:/opt/cabal/1.22/bin:/home/sn/Software/eclipse/cpp-neon/eclipse:/home/sn/Software/jre1.8.0_101/bin:/home/sn/.opam/4.02.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games', 'XDG_VTNR': '7', 'GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL': '/run/user/1000/keyring-ApksQp', 'CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH': '/opt/ros/indigo', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/opt/ros/indigo/lib', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'xterm', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'XDG_SESSION_PATH': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0', 'XAUTHORITY': '/home/sn/.Xauthority', 'LANGUAGE': 'en_US', 'SESSION_MANAGER': 'local/sn-VirtualBox2:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1699,unix/sn-VirtualBox2:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1699', 'SHLVL': '1', 'HACMS': '/home/sn/Projects/HACMS', 'QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME': 'appmenu-qt5', 'JOB': 'dbus', 'TEXTDOMAINDIR': '/usr/share/locale/', 'TEXTDOMAIN': 'im-config', 'QT4_IM_MODULE': 'xim', 'CLUTTER_IM_MODULE': 'xim', 'SESSION': 'ubuntu', 'MANPATH': ':/home/sn/.opam/4.02.1/man', 'SESSIONTYPE': 'gnome-session', 'XMODIFIERS': '@im=ibus', 'ROS_ETC_DIR': '/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros', 'GPG_AGENT_INFO': '/run/user/1000/keyring-ApksQp/gpg:0:1', 'HOME': '/home/sn', 'SELINUX_INIT': 'YES', 'COMPIZ_BIN_PATH': '/usr/bin/', 'CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/home/sn/.opam/4.02.1/lib/stublibs', 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/1000', 'INSTANCE': '', 'PYTHONPATH': '/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 'COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE': 'ubuntu', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/run/user/1000/keyring-ApksQp/ssh', 'VTE_VERSION': '3409', 'ROS_ROOT': '/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros', 'GDMSESSION': 'ubuntu', 'IM_CONFIG_PHASE': '1', 'OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH': '/home/sn/.opam/4.02.1/lib/toplevel', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'GNOME_KEYRING_PID': '', 'XDG_SEAT_PATH': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0', 'ROS_PACKAGE_PATH': '/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks', 'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP': 'Unity', 'XDG_SESSION_ID': 'c1', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS': 'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-owPEPrnTQZ', '_': '/opt/ros/indigo/bin/roscore', 'DEFAULTS_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path', 'PERL5LIB': '/home/sn/.opam/4.02.1/lib/perl5:', 'DESKTOP_SESSION': 'ubuntu', 'UPSTART_SESSION': 'unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1479', 'XDG_CONFIG_DIRS': '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg', 'GTK_MODULES': 'overlay-scrollbar:unity-gtk-module', 'XDG_SEAT': 'seat0', 'OLDPWD': '/home/sn', 'GDM_LANG': 'en_US', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/', 'PWD': '/opt/ros/indigo', 'QT_IM_MODULE': 'ibus', 'ROS_MASTER_URI': 'http://sn-VirtualBox2:11311/', 'COLORTERM': 'gnome-terminal', 'DISPLAY': ':0', 'XDG_MENU_PREFIX': 'gnome-', 'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'USER': 'sn'}
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,191: starting in server mode
[roslaunch.parent][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,191: starting roslaunch parent run
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,191: loading roscore config file /opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros/roscore.xml
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,312: Added core node of type [rosout/rosout] in namespace [/]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,312: start_process_monitor: creating ProcessMonitor
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,312: created process monitor <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, initial daemon)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,313: start_process_monitor: ProcessMonitor started
[roslaunch.parent][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,313: starting parent XML-RPC server
[roslaunch.server][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,313: starting roslaunch XML-RPC server
[roslaunch.server][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,313: waiting for roslaunch XML-RPC server to initialize
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,313: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0:0
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,313: Started XML-RPC server [http://sn-VirtualBox2:36221/]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,314: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,328: started roslaunch server http://sn-VirtualBox2:36221/
[roslaunch.parent][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,328: ... parent XML-RPC server started
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,329: master.is_running[http://sn-VirtualBox2:11311/]
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,350: roscore cannot run as another roscore/master is already running. 
Please kill other roscore/master processes before relaunching.
The ROS_MASTER_URI is http://sn-VirtualBox2:11311/
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,351: The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,364: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 307, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 279, in start
    self.runner.launch()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 654, in launch
    self._setup()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 630, in _setup
    self._launch_master()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 391, in _launch_master
    raise RLException("roscore cannot run as another roscore/master is already running. \nPlease kill other roscore/master processes before relaunching.\nThe ROS_MASTER_URI is %s"%(m.uri))
RLException: roscore cannot run as another roscore/master is already running. 
Please kill other roscore/master processes before relaunching.
The ROS_MASTER_URI is http://sn-VirtualBox2:11311/

[rospy.core][INFO] 2017-01-09 12:50:18,364: signal_shutdown [atexit]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251589/help-unable-to-launch-roscore/) by [sunking](https://answers.ros.org/users/27241/sunking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like something else is listening on port 11311. You may want to double-check that another roscore isn't running (search running process for "ros": `ps aux | grep -i ros`), and you can also look at which process have open ports with `netstat -tlnp`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sunking](https://answers.ros.org/users/27241/sunking/) on 2017-01-09**:
OK thanks I was just doing that - I found that I had apache2 running and when i killed that it was fine